# WPF MediaElement Freezing on last frame when setting Position

Tags: wpf, video, mediaelement

I have a MediaElement in WPF playing a WMV, that I'm rewinding 4 seconds (and I've also tried 4000 Milliseconds with same result). I want to simply loop the last 4 seconds of the video, so i'm ....

```
protected override void videoBase_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //would reset to zero (replay)
    //base.MediaDisplayControl_MediaEnded(sender, e);

    Movie.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4000);
}
```

and it works fine 2-5 times (loops), and then dies on the last frame.

Any ideas?

I should add - that the final MediaElement_MediaEnded event does fire. With logging, i can see that the Position is reset, but the video simply freezes (actually locks up the PC) showing the last frame.

That 2-5 times is important also, because it's repeatable, but not consistent ....

UPDATE - (I'm updating instead of commenting, because there are no responses yet)

The above doesn't happen on an Intel machine, but it does fail on an AMD machine.

The randomness of this is definitely pointing to hardware.

Intel setup ...
T2500 Core Duo
Intel 945 Video Chipset

AMD Setup ...
AMD Athelon 4450B
NVidia Quadro 210S Video Chipset

Just to be clear, on the Intel setup. The video rewinds perfectly, forever. On the AMD setup, the video doesn't rewind.

Hopefully this little bit of knowledge helps jog a memory, and I can get to the bottom of my little mystery. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be a new driver from NVidia.